# Powering LED strips with two power banks and they randomly change different colors when i use the second power bank

Tags: arduino-mega

So for one of my projects i want to power LED strips with power banks but once i try use the second power bank the LEDs half way through patterns jump to random different colors and then go back to the code im using to make sure they work, I dont think its a code issue as when i plug the power into my MEGA it works fine. I would use the MEGA to power the strips but i need 3 power sources to keep my strips at maximum brightness. would this be a voltage drop issue?

When I connected it to my 3 usb port power bank it works perfectly fine so it might be different currents causing it to jump im not to sure if im correct but its definitely something to do with using another power supply is causing my LEDs to randomly change multiple different colors randomly i just cant see if its a current or voltage issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

block diagram [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-EDED7WAER_BU6tCumgxvPttGHeGSt7O/view)

Comment: Greg, we don't know how to answer this. It can be many things. For example the GND level could be lifted by the extra power bank causing the data to turn into noise. This website is about questions and answers. You can update your question, but please remove your answer if it is not an answer.

Comment: Schematic or other wiring diagram?

Comment: Sorry my last link wasnt working heres a block diagram of what ive wired up so far [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1C7xmm0qTyiYK9pplRGKZEqdZXpWcpxRf)

Comment: You should embed the image / diagram in your question. Your link is not public.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-EDED7WAER_BU6tCumgxvPttGHeGSt7O/view?usp=sharing here is a public link sorry i though i made it public my apologizes the P1,P2,P3,P4 are the power bank ports

Comment: you need include the drawing of your circuit in your question, not in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are USB power-banks? You need a way to tie the grounds together somehow. Try tying all the ground lines from your LED strips together and also connecting a wire from one of the LED strips to a ground line on your Arduino.

The USB connections should connect ground between the power bank and the device it's connected to, so by tying the grounds on the LED strips together, that should connect the grounds on the power banks as well.

Comment: Duncan that was the issue making the power bank and the LEDs their separate common GNDs fixed the random lightning of LEDs thank you so much!!!

Comment: Glad I could help. You still need to add your drawing to your question though.